# Disable SSL in local dev environment

Tags: http, ssl, https, hosts

Somehow I've appearantly turned on SSL on my local dev machine, cause when I today try to access a custom hostname (set in /etc/hosts) I'm constantly redirected to the `https` version of the domain.

**Is there any general way to explicitly turn off SSL on my machine?**

I'm not redirected when visiting "normal" websites by `http`, so I guess I can rule out that this is a browser issue?

I'm on Mac OS 10.12.4, and use Puma as local server.

Sorry for not providing info how it has been turned on in the first place, I have no clue how and when this must have happened :/

Comment: Could be HSTS. It's hard to say why the redirect is happening. What browser are you using?

Comment: Updated question stating that this isn't happening when visiting other URLs by `http`, so this shouldn't be caused by my browsers? I didn't know about HSTS beforehand but now when reading about it, it seems not applicable in regard to the added info?

Comment: My concern is that you visited the domain over HTTPS once before adding it to your hosts file, and it enforced HSTS. Now that you've got HSTS marked for the domain, the browser will always redirect to HTTPS no matter where your hosts file points it to.